# How to write this mixin?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I want to write a mixin `TagMixin` which add tag functionality to objects, usage is like:

```
 class Photo(TagMixin): 
     kind = 'photo'
```

or

```
 class Album(TagMixin):
     kind = 'album'
```

The problem is that there are several kinds of tags:

```
class Tag(object):
    table = None

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        r = mysql.execute('select * from %s', cls.table)
        return cls(*r[0]))

    def url(self):
        return NotImplemented

class PhotoTag(Tag):
    table = 'photo_tag' 

    def url(self):
        return '/photo/tag/%s' % self.id

class AlbumTag(Tag):
    table = 'album_tag'

    def url(self):
        return '/album/tag/%s' % self.id
```

and when writing the mixin:

```
class TagMixin(object):

    kind = None

    def get_tags(self):
        tag_ids = mysql.execute('select tag_id from %s_tag_relation where id=%s', (self.kind, self.id))
        return [**Tag**.get(tag_id) for tag_id in tag_ids]
```

and here is the problem:

in the last line of code: `return [**Tag**.get(tag_id)`, `Tag` should be the actual Tag Class (`PhotoTag` or `AlbumTag`, maybe `NoteTag`, `UrlTag` etc in the future)

how could I make a good design of this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where should the class you want come from?  If it's just "the same class as the `self` argument", then you can simply call `self.get(tag_id)`.  It will call the class method `get()` by passing it the class of self.  But explicit is better than implicit: you can also call `self.__class__.get(tag_id)`.